# How to automatically plot multiple series from values in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

In Google Sheets, I know I can plot multiple series into a chart by manually adding a series and selecting/specifying the source data for each series. But is it possible to use a third column to identify each series automatically?

For example, I have columns for X and Y values, and I want to use a third 'Series ID' column to identify which series each point belong to. I have lots of series to plot so setting the sources manually will take too long.

[image: Example data]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it semi-automatically by inserting my own pivot table: Insert > Pivot Table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: From [answer]: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better. I mantion this because just inserting a Pivot Table is not enough. Please briefly explain how a Pivot Table help you to do achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try an unpivot-repivot transformation. Assuming the data is in `Sheet1!A1:C16`, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=query( 
  let( 
    table, Sheet1!A1:C16, 
    numColsToRepeat, 1, 
    numColsToSqueeze, columns(table) - numColsToRepeat, 
    headers, { offset(table, 0, 0, 1, numColsToRepeat), "Category", "Data" }, 
    categories, offset(table, 0, 0, 1), 
    colsToRepeat, offset(table, 1, 0, rows(table) - 1, numColsToRepeat), 
    colsToSqueeze, offset(table, 1, numColsToRepeat, rows(table) - 1, numColsToSqueeze), 
    reduce( 
      { headers, "Row #" }, colsToSqueeze, 
      lambda( 
        result, cell, 
        if( 
          cell = "", 
          result, 
          { 
            result; 
            { 
              index(colsToRepeat, row(cell) - row(colsToSqueeze) + 1), 
              index(categories, 1, column(cell) - column(table) + 1), 
              cell, 
              row(cell) 
            } 
          } 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "select Col2, max(Col3), Col4 
   group by Col2, Col4 
   pivot Col1 order by Col4", 1 
)
```

Then select the first three columns and choose **Insert > Chart**. Use the **Switch rows/columns** option if necessary.

Note that both X and Y will be plotted against the same vertical axis. If your data consists of numbers like `100` and percentages like `25%`, the percentages will be close to invisible. You can address that by recasting the percentages as percentage points by multiplying them by `100` or before transforming the data.

Comment: Cool. I tried that but I think something is off as the result looks weird. But your "pivot" keyword helped me experiment with the "Insert > Pivot Table" feature thing... which I can setup to do what I think your formula is trying to do.

Comment: Adjust the `Sheet1!A1:C16` in the formula so that it points to the real location of your data.

Comment: I didn't mark it as correct or vote because it was only partially correct...